# How can I change the "Memory & threads" limit in ImageJ?

Tags: ram, image-processing

I'm trying to open (import) one raw image (.b) of 750MB, but in **Edit > Options > Memory&threads** the limit is 444MB, and it does not allow to change it.

So I have tried changing this line:

```
mem=${free_mem}/3*2
```

to

```
mem=${free_mem}/6*5
```

in `/usr/bin/imagej`

but it does not change anything.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit, 8G of RAM... I would like to be able to use it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Fiji](https://fiji.sc/) it is possible to change the setting in **Edit > Options > Memory&threads**.

need to close and re-launch to make the modification effective.